# How to set more than one value to a child in Firebase using Swift?

Tags: swift, database, firebase

I am trying to make a money related app which shows the user their spendings as a project to get used to Firebase. So I stumbled upon this issue; I can't seem to figure out how to add more than one expense assigned to a user. Whenever I add a new expense, the existing value in Firebase gets reset to the new value but I want it to store both the new and the old value. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide what you have done far.

Comment: You use a set value but you should use updatechildvalues

Comment: when I use updateChildValues it puts the userID into a; Optional("") statement

Comment: In general, please provide code and your Firebase structure (as TEXT please, no images) so we can formulate a good answer based on what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There's something called "autoID" if that helps. I'll link that in a few moments.

Edit: It's used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858583/firebase-database-storing-unique-key-to-child-nodeswift-ios).

Answer (score 0):

childByAutoId() is what you want for swift. See Updating Or Deleting specific data section in the [Read and Write Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

```
let thisUserRef = ref.child("users").child(users uid)
let expenseRef = thisUserRef.child("expenses").childByAutoId()
let dict = ["expense_type": "travel", "expense_amt": "1.99"]
expenseRef.setValue(dict)
```

will results in

```
users
  uid_0
    -Y88jn90skda //<- the node key created with childByAutoId
       expense_type: "travel"
       expense_amt: "1.99"
```

the childByAutoId is super powerful and allows 'random' node keys to be generated that contain your child data.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386373/compare-textfield-text-to-firebase-string-swift/41387240#41387240) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333862/how-to-write-to-the-last-child-of-a-firebase-ref-in-swift/41335894#41335894) for some tips on data modeling and queries.